# How can I create an item that changes the appearance of things the wearer is scared of?

Tags: dnd-5e

So we organised an in-game Secret Santa for our D&D 5e game, and I got our dear half-vampire (monk work-around). She is terrified of insects (ironic, I know).

I would like to give her a pair of sunglasses, but imbue them with a spell, that changes the appearance of anything you're scared of when worn.

Our DM is allowing a rule of cool to a certain extent, as long as it's not ridiculous. How can I make this work using existing spells, or anything similar?

Comment: Did you ask this question to your DM? What does they say?

Comment: There is no spell that "creates an item that changes the appearance of thing the wearer is scared of", unless your DM homebrews one. What the real goal is? Do you want to to help the character not to be frightened?

Comment: How this illusion is supposed to help with her fear, anyways? "Your clothes are full of bugs, but you don't see them" hardly helps..

Answer (score 1):

If it's just insects, you could try a simple Minor Illusion (make insects appear as lights, or really anything else you'd want) along with the first-level bard/paladin spell Heroism, which grants immunity to being frightened + temporary hp equal to your spellcasting ability modifier for a minute? If you're a bard you can just do this yourself but otherwise find a fellow player/npc to enchant it (talk to your DM). As for making it react when your friend sees insects, you could prooobably use the "hold an action" mechanic long-term with the glasses? Again, talk to your DM about making all this possible, but those are the best two spells I can think of to make this sort of thing happen.

Comment: Apparently, Minor Illusion can not make one thing look like another, at least while this thing are moving. But I agree the right question should be "how to help a character not to be frightened", not "how to create an item that changes the appearance of things".